# How to remove a inserted tree from registry using command line?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I am have imported .reg file to registry using command line utility (as admin).

```
regedit /s myregfile.reg
```

To remove MyTree I have used following command but it does not work.

```
regedit [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\MyTree] // suppose to remove MyTree
```

Can anybody suggest me solution to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reg delete HKLM\MyTree` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer:

`regedit`, when in import mode, always takes a **file name**. So giving it "[-HKLM\MyTree]" will not work unless you happen to have a valid Registry file named that. So you would need to create a temporary file and import it (unfortunately, there's no direct equivalent to `/dev/stdin` in Windows), like a file with the following contents (always a blank line after the first):

```
REGEDIT4

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\MyTree]
```

(Using the `reg` command is a lot better. But this may be helpful for when it's not available.)